# Laravel 5.4 - use a custom attribute model in a collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

- I have the model `Order`.
- Order *has many* `Item`.
- An `Item` has a `price` attribute (from the database).
- An `Order` has a `getAmountAttribute` method which looks like this:

---

```
/**
 * @return double
 */

public function getAmountAttribute()
{
    return $this->items->sum('price');
}


/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

So I can fetch the total price of order's items by simply doing `$order->amount`.

---

Now I have a collection of `Order` and I want to fetch every order that its total price starts at 10. How can I achieve that since I can't use my custom attribute on a `where` statement?

Comment: If you have an existing collection, just run a loop. Otherwise you probably want a custom SQL query.

Comment: `filter()` on a collection should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via `->havingRaw('SUM(price) > 10')`

Answer (score 0):

You can get only the desired collection of orders(orders with total price starting at 10) instead of getting all the collection of orders and fetching the desired orders.

```
->get(function($order) {
        return $order->amount > 10;
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way I can achieve this goal before executing the `get` method? I mean when ur still "building" the collection.

Comment: @Eliya yes. that is what I've answered.